# Rock, paper, scissor game in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[https://github.com/VilloKodeHode/Final-Portfolio/tree/master/src/component/RockPaperScissor](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I dont have that long experience with react yet, and Im doing a project that is a pain. Im trying to figure out how to implement a "const result" in my code so it can check for "win", "lose" or "draw". I've tried many different approaches, but have yet to be successfull. Any wise ideas?

Btw, this is my first post on stackoverflow, so if my post is inadequate on info or something else tell me and I'll try to fix it.

I tried:

```
function PlayRound({ setComputerPick, setScore }, playerPick) {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
  let computerPick;
  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    computerPick = "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
    computerPick = "paper";
  } else {
    computerPick = "scissors";
  }

  console.log(
    "computer picked from the ComputerPick function: " + computerPick
  );
 ** let result = "";**
  setComputerPick(computerPick);
  if (
    (playerPick === "rock" && computerPick === "scissors") ||
    (playerPick === "scissors" && computerPick === "paper") ||
    (playerPick === "paper" && computerPick === "rock")
  ) {
    setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 1);
**    result = "win";**

    console.log(
      "Results from Playround function: playerpick: " + playerPick,
      "computerpick: " + computerPick
    );
  } else if (
    (playerPick === "rock" && computerPick === "paper") ||
    (playerPick === "scissors" && computerPick === "rock") ||
    (playerPick === "paper" && computerPick === "scissors")
  ) {
 **   result = "lose";**

    setScore((prevScore) => prevScore - 1);
  } else {
     **result = "draw"**
  }
  
  console.log(result);

  return (
   <>
      {computerPick === "rock" && (
        <GameButton color="red" id="RockButton" src={ROCK} />
      )}
      {computerPick === "paper" && (
        <GameButton color="blue" id="PaperButton" src={PAPER} />
      )}
      {computerPick === "scissors" && (
        <GameButton color="yellow" id="ScissorsButton" src={SCISSORS} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

I cant figure out how to use this in my RockPaperScissor function to make the changes I want to do... Like if result="win" the player button should light up, and computer button if result="lose".